# Servlet.init() для сервлета [dispatcher] выбросил исключение

Tags: java, maven, spring-security

Начинаю изучать spring security, выбрасывается исключение, в чем может быть проблема?

pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <groupId>com.zaurtregulov.spring.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_course_security</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 
  <name>spring_course_security Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
 
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
 
  </dependencies>
 
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_course_security</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

MyConfig:

```
package com.zaurtregulov.spring.security.configuration;
 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
 
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.zaurtregulov.spring.security")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
 
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

MyWebInitializer:

```
package com.zaurtregulov.spring.security.configuration;
 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
 
public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
 
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MyConfig.class};
    }
 
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

MySecurityInitializer:

```
package com.zaurtregulov.spring.security.configuration;
 
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
 
public class MySecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

MySecurityConfig:

```
package com.zaurtregulov.spring.security.configuration;
 
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.UserBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
 
@EnableWebSecurity
 
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserBuilder userBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
 
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(userBuilder.username("matvey").password("matvey").roles("EMPLOYEE"))
                .withUser(userBuilder.username("ivan").password("ivan").roles("HR"))
                .withUser(userBuilder.username("matvey").password("matvey").roles("MANAGER", "HR"));
    }
}
```

В итоге вместо страницы с аутентификацией вылетает исключение с месседжем Servlet.init() для сервлета [dispatcher] выбросил исключение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если Servlet.init() выбросил исключение то это означает то, что @EnableWebMvc не работает, уберите эту аннотацию и сконфигурируйте webmvc вручную.

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста вопрос скриншотом всех файлов проекта, а также полным stack trace exception если возможно.

Comment: @RomanC а почему EnableWebMvc не работает, я повторяю все, как в видео из курсов, там работает, у меня нет

Comment: @kyt3 Держи, файлов в основном больше нет, проблемы с конфигурацией только

Comment: @Matvey Кинь ссылку на видеокурс, я хочу посмотреть. Потом, скриншоты экрана делать не нужно, вместо этого надо скопировать текст из консоли и поместить в вопрос.

Comment: @kyt3 Там его скачивать нужно, это слив курсов, я делал в точности, как там, то что не думаю, что чем-то поможет https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qONAdz4iqfin_eE6App0Yt7uJloiMbVg/view

Answer (score 0):

У Вас идентичный случай с [Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616569/error-creating-bean-with-name-springsecurityfilterchain/28655714).

А именно: дубляж в именах пользователей, два `matvey` в классе `MySecurityConfig`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
    public EntityManager makeEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
```

я добавила в `HibernateConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Тоже была эта ошибка решил заменой

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

на

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```